# list item dividers in wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, list, menu, menuitem

I have menu items listed. i have a custom seperator I would like. Currently I have styled the menu items with a background image of the divider positioned to the left. I want to remove the first one.

i.e. my menu looks like this:
/   work  /   about   /   resume   /   contact   /   store

i want it to look like:
/   work  /   about   /   resume   /   contact   /   store

menu styled:

```
.main-nav ul li a {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 22pt;
    color:#999999;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    width:190px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(data/img/navdivider.png);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:65px;
    padding-top:8px;
}
```

trying to get rid of first one with:

```
.main-nav ul li a:first-child {
    background-image:none;
}
```

but its not working. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited whole answer, because it was wrong.
Problem is that you are targeting `a` as a `:first-child`, which always is (its parent is that `li` element). So, try target with this:

```
.main-nav ul li:first-child a {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Comment: ugh sorry!let me clarify what doesn't work. i think its something with the first-child psuedo. when i apply that code, it removes all background images. how do I make sure it only targets the first?

i tried the shorthands, it didn't change anything

Comment: you are the most awesome person ever! thank you so much. i'm new to the child tags. fixed the problem :)